# How to remove_action if add_action is in abstract class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and I need to remove an action that the activated theme is adding.

I know I can do it simply adding `remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority );` but that doesn't work for me.

**Theme is adding `add_action` through an abstract class like this:**

```
abstract class foo {

   public function __construct() {

      add_action('wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', array(&$this, 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom', 10));

   }

}
```

**And here is the subclass that is implementing the above abstract class:**

```
class bar extends foo {

    public function __contruct() {}

}

new bar();
```

And there is no `$variable` assigned to the instance of the subclass that implements this abstract class.

So I want to remove this action through my plugin but not sure how?

My plugin is also `OOP` based. So any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You need to find the variable assigned to the instance of the subclass that implements that abstract class. Hopefully it will be accessible in the plugin. You may need to try to make it global.

Comment: What if there is no variable assigned to that class?

Comment: Please, try put a priority > to 2000 `remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, 2001 );`

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates Didn't work :(

Comment: Please if you comment that line, it work fine?

Comment: Which line are you talking about? @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates

Comment: @Omer It won't be a variable assigned to the abstract class "foo". Abstract classes require a subclass to implement the methods. So somewhere there is a class "bar" that extends "foo" and there will need to be an instance of "bar" somewhere. `$bar = new bar;`

Comment: global $wp_filter; 
in that var are saved all filter and actions
and you can do it a search with the wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom
and get the real class/object

Comment: @BA_Webimax Updated my question... there is no variable assigned to the instance of the subclass that implements this abstract class.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates I tried `$wp_filter` in the plugin but couldn't found the `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom` in it but when I print the `$wp_filter` from with in the theme it shows `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom` ... Why its showing different data if I print it from the theme and from plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, that method of creating a class instance is completely wrong. Sometimes you can't just work with broken code in a reasonable manner. However, I've seen some authors do this while also implementing a `getInstance()` method.

If the class you are working with contains a method like that, you can do something like

```
remove_action( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', array( bar::getInstance(), 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom' ), 10 );
```

If the theme author was completely without a clue, then there is still one last resort. There is a pair of functions that can be included in your code base to overcome this programming error. It can be found here...

https://github.com/herewithme/wp-filters-extras/

**Update:**

Hmm, I just looked up the "wp_edit_nav_menu_walker" hook. It's a filter not an action. Your sample was a little misleading.

I believe it would be easier to override the filter with the default Walker Class like so. Make sure the priority is higher than the one in the theme. You will also need to modify the code below to work in your OOP plugin.

```
function restore_edit_walker( $walker, $menu_id ) 
{
    return 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit';
}
add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'restore_edit_walker', 11, 2 );
```

Comment: No there is no method like `getInstance()` in that class :(

Comment: I guess you'll have to go grab those functions then. They work, they are just a bit of a sledgehammer and shouldn't be necessary with good coding practices.

Comment: Ok grabbed those function and they works fine in theme's function.php but when I put in my plugin's file it doesn't work. I also checked those functions that are using the same technique mentioned by @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenate on my question. It checks the `$wp_filter` variable and unset targeted set. But I checked the `$wp_filter` from theme and from plugin with `print_r()` its data is different in both scenario.

Comment: Plugins load well before the theme. So those actions haven't been added yet to be removed. Try wrapping your `remove_action()` call in a hook that loads after the theme has loaded like `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Yes I can see that its a filter... but it still workin action. Is this possible?

Comment: `add_action` is a wrapper for `add_filter`, so it is entirely possible. Using the wrong one makes the code less readable and changes what is possible when trying to override. In this case the "wp_edit_nav_menu_walker" filter does nothing more than return the name of a class. Instead of needing to remove it, you could just do the same thing a second time and use the WP core Walker class as demonstrated above.

Comment: So you are overriding it back to default instead of removing it?

Comment: Yes, as long as your filter is the last one in the stack, it will override all other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a very long discussion with [@BA_Webimax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895481/ba-webimax) and [@JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153237/jose-carlos-ramos-carmenates) and hours of testing I have found a simple solution.

I could not have done it without these two guys. They shared a lot of information which helped me understand so much of how stuff is working.

So I just came up with the idea of using `$wp_filter` variable by [@JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153237/jose-carlos-ramos-carmenates) and get some basic understanding of how to use it from [@BA_Webimax's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895481/ba-webimax) link [WP Filters Extras](https://github.com/herewithme/wp-filters-extras/) that he shared in his answer and a simple hook `after_setup_theme` which is shared with me by my beautiful wife :p

**Lets put everything together:**

```
function custom_remove_action() {
    global $wp_filter;

    foreach ( $wp_filter['wp_edit_nav_menu_walker'][10] as $key => $value ) {

        // Check the hook if its the one we want to remove
        if ( $value['function'][1] == 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker_custom' ) {
            unset($wp_filter['wp_edit_nav_menu_walker'][10][$key]);
        }

    }
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_remove_action');
```

But it seems like [@BA_Webimax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895481/ba-webimax) came up with the right answer by overriding the hook again.

Shared mine if anyone want to do it this way :)